# How do I set up a remote ssh connection from my raspberry pi?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I really need some clarification regarding how you connect to a remote server which then forwards requests to certain ports. In an ssh tunnel, are you establishing a SOCKS proxy? How do I get a server to forward requests to my pi at home? I would be unbelievably grateful for help. Thanks :))

Comment: In general, you will install/configure network on the *remote server* to perform [*port forwarding*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/57721/how-to-forward-a-port-from-one-machine-to-another). If the *remote server* is a Linux/Unix machine, there are several ways to do this assuming you have root/su privileges on that machine. One way to accomplish this is via `ssh`; but `ssh` on the *remote server* must be configured to do port forwarding. [`ncat` may be useful.](https://www.linuxtechi.com/nc-ncat-command-examples-linux-systems/) Please provide more specifics; we'll try to help.

Comment: I use ssh tunneling to forward ports so I won't have to publicly expose more than a single port through NAT. This is not SOCKS though. It may be easier to help you if you explain more directly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you,

**ssh RPI_Uname@RPI_IPaddress** Hit enter

Then type your **RPI Password**

Example:

**ssh pi@10.14.83.145**

May this will help you.